# sys.database_files DMV, max_size column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, dmv

I was just modifying my script that I use to get size of database file and wanted to use `max_size`  to display if a max size was set for a database file.  As per Microsoft Docs, the column description is

> Maximum file size, in 8-KB pages:
>
> 0 = No growth is allowed.
>
> -1 = File will grow until the disk is full.
>
> 268435456 = Log file will grow to a maximum size of 2 TB.

I feel like I am missing something obvious, but under what condition does it show a value of 0?  I tried removing autogrowth and it comes up as -1.

Comment: I think this is a bug. I posted in the tweeter and also posted a feedbackhttps://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/39339244-max-size-column-in-master-files-and-database-files